# Is there any way to swipe to delete/ Add actions into cell in UITableview Diffable datasource?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swift5

I am trying to add swipe actions into my tableview. when I used simple tableview datasource method it worked fine (trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt). but when I tried the same thing with Diffable datasource it didn't even call the method for swiping. I used breakpoints to get followup but it didn't work.
I am using swift 5 (UIKit), Xcode 12.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by following method:
Used subclass of diffabled datasource as follows.

```
class GrocDataSource: UITableViewDiffableDataSource <GrocListSections, Grocs> {
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section == 2 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

}

Implemented this class into datasource as:

```
datasource = GrocDataSource(tableView: grocTableView, cellProvider: { (tableView, indexPath, grocs) in
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GrocNameCell", for: indexPath) as? GrocNameCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
return cell })
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a demo and it works fine.

[image]

##### CustomDiffableDataSource.swift

```swift
import UIKit

enum Section: CaseIterable {
    case main
}

struct City: Hashable {
    var name: String
    let identifier = UUID()

    func contains(query: String?) -> Bool {
        guard let query = query else {
            return true
        }

        guard !query.isEmpty else {
            return true
        }

        return name.contains(query)
    }
}

class CustomDiffableDataSource: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Section, City> {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("delete")
        
        // get item data
        guard let item = itemIdentifier(for: indexPath) else {
            return
        }
        
        print("item: ", item)
    }
}
```

##### TableViewController.swift

```swift
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    lazy var cities: [City] = {
        let cityNames = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
        var cities = [City]()
        for name in cityNames {
            cities.append(City(name: name))
        }

        return cities
    }()

    var dataSource: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Section, City>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        createDataSource()
    }

    func createDataSource() {
        dataSource = CustomDiffableDataSource(tableView: tableView, cellProvider: { tableView, _, city in
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
            cell?.textLabel?.text = city.name

            return cell
        })

        dataSource.defaultRowAnimation = .fade

        show()
    }

    func show() {
        var snapshot = dataSource.snapshot()

        snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        snapshot.appendItems(cities, toSection: .main)

        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
    }
}
```